# How can I align the text in the right side but the text start from the left side

Tags: html, css

I'm making a footer for my website so I made the left side and right side, left is good but the right needs some changes [I want to make the writing on the right side starting from the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfCaW.png)

**HTML code**

```
   <div class="footer-right">
        <h1>Get In touch</h1>
        <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Location</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>example@gmail.com</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Phone Number:---------</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple css you just need to align the text of that box to the right

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  }
 .footer-left {
  width: 50%;
 }
.footer-right {  
  width: 50%;
 }
 
 .alignright {
  text-align: right;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="footer-left">
    <p>text that is on the left side box</p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-right">
      
        <h1>Get In touch</h1>
        <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Location</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>example@gmail.com</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Phone Number:---------</p>
        
        <!-- in case you want the text to the right just text align it. -->
        <div class="alignright">
          <h1>Get In touch</h1>
          <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Location</p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>example@gmail.com</p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Phone Number:---------</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added an example on the box that is to the right with text either to the left and another example right there with text to the right.

Comment: you did not understand me I did that code, What I want is to start from the left while it on right, go look to the pic.

Comment: It depends how you have your Div setup you can either use flex which is the recommended or float the div the old ways, ill add to examples to see if that is what you are referring to